# is it possible to run a task scheduler in bottle web framework

Tags: python, task, scheduler, bottle

Does anyone have any examples on how to integrate a task scheduler in Bottle. Something like APScheduler or sched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest threading it allows the webserver to be unaffected by the scheduled tasks that will either be in a queue or written into the code itself.