# How to add scheduler to Bottle

Tags: python-3.x, bottle, apscheduler

I'm completely new to Python and Bottle (and apscheduler) so would appreciate some simple instructions on implementing a scheduled job.

I have written some Python code that can check the status and data displayed on one of our websites. I have also written some code that emails the status to us.

Now, I would like to add functionality to call this code regularly (e.g. every 15 minutes) and, for this, apscheduler seems to be a suitable, lightweight, self-contained solution.

What I would like to know is:

- Can I start a BackgroundScheduler when the Bottle website starts?  (Where is the "start up" code situated?)
- And can I make my instance of the BackgroundScheduler global? The reason is that I want to access it from elsewhere on the site and add/remove/pause jobs

I saw that someone else had a similar idea here [is it possible to run a task scheduler in bottle web framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477310/is-it-possible-to-run-a-task-scheduler-in-bottle-web-framework) but the details and answer have too little detail for a noob like me.

I understand that I could probably wrangle something similar using sleep() but I first want to explore the apscheduler option first.

I did also look at Celery but I think that is overkill for this small, single-purpose web application that I am building.

I should add that I am using a Bottle project available in Visual Studio 2013, which comes with certain configuration and files already included.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [threading.Timer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects) :

```
from threading import Timer

def my_task():
    # do stuff ...
    Timer(15*60, my_task).start()     # schedule for every 15 minutes

# start your scheduler
my_task()
```

Answer (score 0):

@Alexander: I did this too. It works with the *Botte WSGIRefServer()*, here you can have threads living as long as you like. On an Apache with *mod_wsgi* your threads supposed to be running only for so long - then they are killed. So a scheduler *inside* Bottle did not work for me.

Personaly I'm writing a little *schedule server* in zmq (pyzmq) which receives scheduled task and uses [schedule-package](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to run them. Works well for me.